# how to insert array 2d in table mysql with php if sub array diferent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i will ask how to insert array if amount sub arrays not same, i have problem if the $arrays != 3 because in sub arrays 2 in arrays one

```
<?php
$arrays=array(
        array('a','b'),
        array('a','b','c'),
        array('a','b','c')
    );
$per=0;
for ($h=0; $h < count($arrays); $h++) { 
    if (count($arrays) > $per) {
        $per= count($arrays);
     }
}

$koneksi = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","data");

$nil=array();
foreach ($arrays as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $data[$key];  
    }
     $nil[]="('".implode("', '",$data). "')";
 }

$insert="INSERT INTO datams (data1,data2,data3) VALUES ".implode(', ',$nil);

 $queri=mysqli_query($koneksi, $insert);

 if ($queri == true){
    echo 'upload done'.PHP_EOL;
  } else {
     echo 'fail upload'.PHP_EOL;
  }
```

i can't insert the data if sub array same, can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the arrays the same length.

Create an empty array, then loop your existing array, adding the missing values using [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php). After that, you can insert them.

```
$empty=['' , '' , ''];

foreach($array as $key => $tmp){
   $array[$key] = array_replace($empty,$tmp); 
   // This replaces the values of $empty with those of $array that are set:
   // ['','',''] replace wihh ['a','b','c'] gives ['a','b','c']
   // ['','',''] replace with ['a','b']     gives ['a','b','']
   }
```

You will end up with:

```
$arrays=array(
        array('a','b','' ),
        array('a','b','c'),
        array('a','b','c')
    );
```

Now you can insert the values;

**EDIT**

To make it more flexible (i.e the original array keeps changing), you first have to find the length of the longest array in `$array`.

```
$max=0; 
foreach($array as $a) {
    $c = count($a);
    if( $c > $max) $max = $c; 
    }
$empty=array_fill(0,$max,'');
```

Comment: How if this array not 3 but can dinamic because every array amount not same , this array from data crawling

Comment: @exsanrenaldhi Added flexible version.

Comment: thanks for answer  its work, now how to compare array 2 dimension but with flexible key arrays

Comment: @exsanrenaldhi Perhaps you should try something yourself first. If it doesn't work then ask a new question. This question is answered, and if it works you should accept the answer.